# Does IIS pause execution of ASP.NET MVC application when there is no activity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I'm seeing a really strange behavior in one of my applications.  It is an ASP.NET MVC application, running in IIS7.  I have a very small bit of code that is running out of the context of any request (think of a basic heartbeat over a TCP socket).  However, I notice that when there is no activity, the heartbeat seems to stop.  If I simply make a request against the site, everything is peachy again.

So, my question is, what is the expected behavior of code running outside of any request context?

Comment: In general running non request handling threads in iis is a bad idea, interestingly this was a recent topic on Phil Haacks blog http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: @meandmycode Nice link, thans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, IIS application pools will stop after 20 minutes of inactivity.

[Configure Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28WS.10%29.aspx)